# Non vanishing differential form

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

I am in trouble with the proof of this theorem:

Let $\Lambda^m(T^*M)$ be trivial: then there exist a nowhere vanishing $\omega$ $\in$ $\Omega^m(M)$

In particular at the beginning of the proof a generic atlas is considered:

Let ${(U_{\alpha},\Psi_{\alpha})}$ be any atlas (not necessarily oriented):

$\Rightarrow$ $\forall \alpha$ $\Psi_{\alpha}^*(dx_1\wedge...\wedge dx_m)= f_\alpha \cdot \omega$

where $f_\alpha$ : $U_{\alpha}$ $\longrightarrow$ $\mathbf{R}$ is non-vanishing.

What I don't understand is this last equality and also why $\Psi_{\alpha}^*(dx_1 \wedge ... \wedge dx_m)$ is non vanishing.

Comment: You might have confused some things since 1) you want to prove the existence of $\omega$, but 2) you say you use $\omega$ at the beginning of the proof

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, $m=\dim M$.
The existence of such a non-vanishing form is immediate: by assumption, there is a bundle isomorphism
$$
F\colon \Lambda^m(T^*M) \overset{\sim}{\to} M\times \Bbb R.
$$
Consider the constant section $s$ of $M\times \Bbb R$ given by
$s(p) = (p,1)$.
It is a nowhere vanishing section.
Now, $\omega = F^* s$ is a nowhere vanishing section of $\Lambda^m(T^*M)$.

**Once such a non vanishing section $\omega$ have been proven to exist**, for any (local) differential $m$-form $\sigma$, there exists a function $f$ such that $\sigma = f \omega$.
This is because $\Lambda^m(T^*M)$ is a rank one vector bundle, and therefore, $\omega(p)$ is a basis of the one dimensional vector space $\Lambda^m(T^*M)_p$, for all $p$.
You can apply this to $\varphi^*(dx^1\wedge \cdots \wedge dx^m)$ for any chart $\varphi$.

Comment: really thank you, now I understand the equality. May I ask you why what you called $\varphi(dx_1 \wedge ... \wedge dx_m)$ is non-vanishing? (so that also $f_{\alpha}$ is non vanishing)

Comment: $\varphi$ is a diffeomorphism from its domain to its codomain, and $dx^1\wedge \cdots \wedge dx^m$ is non-vanishing on the codomain. Call $\sigma = \varphi^*(dx^1\wedge \cdots \wedge dx^m)$. If $\sigma = f \omega$ with both $\sigma$ and $\omega$ non-vanishing, can you deduce that $f\neq 0$?

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!